# Create a short url that passes a parameter into another

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

I'm looking to create a linking system where a short address with a parameter is redirected using the parameter in the destination link.

HTTP://www.example.com/track.php?PARAMETER=12345

redirects to the below address inserting the variables at the end of the link above into the PARAMETER slot.

HTTP://www.exampletwo.com/track/home/trackingbynumber.asp?PARAMETER=12345&other=XXXXXX&and=YYYYYY

Here's what I'm trying with no luck:

```php
<?php
 $url = "track.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
 header("Location: http://exampletwo.com/track/home/trackingbynumber.asp".'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']&other=XXXXXX&and=YYYYYY);
?>
```

Comment: "*Is this some that could be scripted in PHP or HTML?*" Sure can (although HTML isn't a scripting language). What have you tried so far to accomplish this? Where in that attempt are you getting stuck?

Comment: use a [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect, but `?12345` wont magically turn into `?PARAMETER=12345&other=XXXXXX&and=YYYYYY`, your need php because html alone cant access the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the below:

Link looks like: HTTP://www.example.com/track.php?PARAMETER=12345

The track.php:

```html
<?php
$PARAMETER = $_GET['PARAMETER'];
header("Location: http://www.exampletwo.com/track/home/trackingbynumber.asp?PARAMETER=$PARAMETER&other=XXXXXX&and=YYYYYY");
?>
```